# What does quadrature mean in the context of sine waves and resonance?

Tags: optics, waves, terminology, interferometry

I heard a professor talk about [quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_(mathematics)) in a sine wave representing resonance in time. What is the quadrature of the wave, and what does it mean for a quadrature to shift?

To be more specific, a quadrature shift in the wave generated by testing resonance with an interferometer. I have no idea what the quadrature is and why it would shift.

Comment: heard where? in what context?

Comment: The prof was talking about a problem that arises when using fabry-perot interferometry to measure resonance, and how a problem of stability would be that the quadrature shifts, and the peak of the waves oscillate. Now you know as much as i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a signal $s(t)$ which oscillates at a frequency $f$. In general, such a signal will look like a sine wave offset by an arbitrary phase $\phi$
\begin{equation}
s(t) = A \sin(2\pi f t + \phi)
\end{equation}
You can think of the phase of this signal as a vector in a two dimensional plane, with $\phi$ being the angle between the $x$ axis and the phase vector (phasor), and $A$ being the amplitude.

Using some trig identities, we can decompose the signal into *cosine* and *sine* *quadratures* (sometimes also called *in phase* and *quadrature* components), as follows
\begin{equation}
s(t) = A \sin (2\pi f t) \cos \phi + A \cos (2\pi f t) \sin \phi
\end{equation}
In the picture of the phasor is represented by a 2-dimensional vector, this amounts to resolving the phasor into $x$ and $y$ components.

There's some helpful content on wikipedia as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-phase_and_quadrature_components